# Rread from Variables from class in Function

Tags: python

How can I output everything from a class?

I would like to use the "`read()`" function for this.

I created the `test.py` file as a python file and created the `items.py` as a package

`test.py`:

```
from library.items import Playlists


def add():
    list = []
    list.append(Playlists('24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq', 'Auto', '3AzjcOeAmA57TIOr9zF1ZW'))
    list.append(Playlists('24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq', 'Auto', '45bE4HXI0AwGZXfZtMp8JR'))
    list.append(Playlists('7jA9b083jD5GTejPovTVX9', 'Auto2', '5gJ7XTF7e0shYzCOAfwsIz'))
    list.append(Playlists('7jA9b083jD5GTejPovTVX9', 'Auto2', '1K3MWIZ1wuy6HjDLo63ZgT'))
    list.append(Playlists('7jA9b083jD5GTejPovTVX9', 'Auto2', '5uKgxudNcssSnULVAkpkwI'))
    list.append(Playlists('6Z7CHHGD33XtVjLJ3WFIiW', 'Auto3', '0sjSgTluUJIdqfyRe4EQ4U'))
    list.append(Playlists('6Z7CHHGD33XtVjLJ3WFIiW', 'Auto3', '2TfcMUAZ4vH4fTA9eF53v2'))
    list.append(Playlists('6Z7CHHGD33XtVjLJ3WFIiW', 'Auto3', '0YOUE1TlkgSbkNvWkZkEVp'))
    list.append(Playlists('6Z7CHHGD33XtVjLJ3WFIiW', 'Auto3', '3AKm9sJmK0v3wUQYSLuze7'))


def read():
    test = Playlists.__str__()
    print(f'Playlist ID: {playlist_id}, Playlist Mame: {playlist_name}, Track ID: {track_id}')


def main():
    add()
    read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`item.py`:

```
class Playlists:

    def __init__(self, playlist_name, playlist_id, track_id):
        self.playlist_name = playlist_name
        self.playlist_id = playlist_id
        self.track_id = track_id
        # print(f'Playlist Name: {self.playlist_name}, Playlist ID: {self.playlist_id}, Track ID: 
{self.track_id}')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Playlist Name: {self.playlist_name}, Playlist ID: {self.playlist_id}, Track ID: 
{self.track_id},'
```

Answer (score 1):

currently, the `add` function creates a list of `Playlist`s but does nothing with it. I'd recomend to return that list in the end of the function. And in the `read` function, take a list as a parameter and print all the playlists in that list. So the updated code would be:

```py
from library.items import Playlists


def add():
    list = []
    list.append(Playlists('24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq', 'Auto', '3AzjcOeAmA57TIOr9zF1ZW'))
    list.append(Playlists('24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq', 'Auto', '45bE4HXI0AwGZXfZtMp8JR'))
    list.append(Playlists('7jA9b083jD5GTejPovTVX9', 'Auto2', '5gJ7XTF7e0shYzCOAfwsIz'))
    list.append(Playlists('7jA9b083jD5GTejPovTVX9', 'Auto2', '1K3MWIZ1wuy6HjDLo63ZgT'))
    list.append(Playlists('7jA9b083jD5GTejPovTVX9', 'Auto2', '5uKgxudNcssSnULVAkpkwI'))
    list.append(Playlists('6Z7CHHGD33XtVjLJ3WFIiW', 'Auto3', '0sjSgTluUJIdqfyRe4EQ4U'))
    list.append(Playlists('6Z7CHHGD33XtVjLJ3WFIiW', 'Auto3', '2TfcMUAZ4vH4fTA9eF53v2'))
    list.append(Playlists('6Z7CHHGD33XtVjLJ3WFIiW', 'Auto3', '0YOUE1TlkgSbkNvWkZkEVp'))
    list.append(Playlists('6Z7CHHGD33XtVjLJ3WFIiW', 'Auto3', '3AKm9sJmK0v3wUQYSLuze7'))
    return list


def read(list):
    for playlist in list:
        test = Playlists.__str__()
        print(f'Playlist ID: {playlist_id}, Playlist Mame: {playlist_name}, Track ID: {track_id}')


def main():
    list = add()
    read(list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Other changes you can make:**

- In `add`, instead of creating an empty list and then adding items to it, create the list with the items.
- because the `Playlist` class implements a `__str__` method, you can just `print(playlist)` instead of `print(f'Playlist ID:...')`.
- The name `list` hides the built-in type `list`, so it's recomended to use a different name (perhaps "playlists").

Answer (score 0):

yes that was my mistake, the list is not really correct

I changed it

```
test.txt
24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq Auto 3AzjcOeAmA57TIOr9zF1ZW
24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq Auto 45bE4HXI0AwGZXfZtMp8JR
24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq Auto1 0qaWEvPkts34WF68r8Dzx9
24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq Auto2 26wmPj5lkwKMRrQICLNI1a
24SHqUZy0WCV5xr0rf8lKq Auto2 6i7zAdNhzUN2k1HcrBxPHG

item.py
class Playlists:

    def __init__(self, playlist_name, playlist_id, track_id):
        self.playlist_name = playlist_name
        self.playlist_id = playlist_id
        self.track_id = track_id
        #print(f'Playlist Name: {self.playlist_name}, Playlist ID: {self.playlist_id}, Track ID: {self.track_id}')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Playlist Name: {self.playlist_name}, Playlist ID: {self.playlist_id}, Track ID: {self.track_id},'

test.py
from library.items import Playlists
import os

test_file = os.getcwd() + '\\test.txt'


def add():
    with open(test_file) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            line = '{}'.format(line.strip())
            playlist_id, playlist_name, track_id = line.split(' ')
            user_playlists = Playlists(playlist_name, playlist_id, track_id)  # Einfügen in die Class Playlists


def read():
    test = Playlists.__str__()
    print(f'Playlist ID: {playlist_id}, Playlist Mame: {playlist_name}, Track ID: {track_id}')


def main():
    add()
    read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to use a function to query the entered data from Class Playlists again

Regards